# App Bar for windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I would like to show the text of the word rather than hidden. Example from this [image]

I would like to change to show it this way at the start together with the words. Not hidden. 
[image]

After reading the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar_properties(v=vs.105).aspx I still have no idea how to do it. To make the text appear as default.

Comment: Can you please post the link contents, while launching the url I found the "Content not found We could not find the page you requested."

Comment: I don't think thats possible with default ApplicationBar (don't know if any 3rd party support that behavior). As you can see in the link, ApplicationBar has `Mode` property that you can set to `Default` (showing icon button without text and ellipsis at right side) or `Minimized` (ellipsis only without icons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NoobieNeedHelp
ApplicationBar in WP is system object to properties of which you have access, rather than something that you have control of. So only possible options for you minimized mode or default with icons and user can open appbar himself.
Following WP UX guidelines you simply need to provide self-descriptive icons.
Or you if you have very specific usage, you can write your own control that simulates appbar, but i wouldn't recommend it.